# Joining with the same table twice with different conditions

Tags: sql, hiveql

I have a table which contains a summer of user activity in a suite of products for each day. There is theoretically only one row per `<UserId, Product, Client, Date>` tuple, since this table is generated by a `GROUP BY`. Let's call it `UserActivity`.

`UserActivity:`

```
UserId | Product | Client     | Date
------------------------------------------
John   | Bank    | Mobile App | 2019-02-28
John   | Bank    | Desktop App| 2019-02-28
Sally  | Gym     | Web App    | 2019-02-28
```

I have another table, let's call it `FirstLastSeen`, where we have the `UserId`s and when they first used each `Product` and `Client`.

`FirstLastSeen:`

```
UserId | Product | Client     | Date
------------------------------------------
John   | Bank    | Mobile App | 2019-01-01
John   | Bank    | Desktop App| 2019-02-28
Sally  | Gym     | Web App    | 2019-02-28
```

I want to compute if the user is "new" to that `Product` AND if they are new to that `Client`. What that means is the day they first used this `Product` is equal to `Date`, and the date they first used this `Product` AND `Client` is equal to `Date`. So, a table like this:

```
UserId | Product | Client     | Date       | IsNewProduct | IsNewClient
-----------------------------------------------------------------
John   | Bank    | Mobile App | 2019-02-28 | False        | False        // Used on 01-01
John   | Bank    | Desktop App| 2019-02-28 | False        | True         // First time used this client was same day         
Sally  | Bank    | Mobile App | 2019-02-28 | True         | True         // First time we saw her in this product and client
```

One way to do this is:

```
SELECT 
    UA.UserId, 
    UA.Product, 
    UA.Client, 
    CASE FLS.Date = UA.DATE THEN True ELSE FALSE END AS FirstSeenClient
FROM UserActivity as UA
LEFT JOIN FirstLastSeen AS FLS 
    ON  UA.UserId=FLS.UserId 
    AND UA.Product=FLS.Product 
    AND UA.Client=FLS.Client;
```

This would give me `FirstSeenClient` that I want. There is guaranteed to be a row corresponding to their usage. I don't know how to get `FirstSeenProduct`. I suspect the answer is in a subquery or window functions but I'm unsure how to write it, potentially `MIN(Date) OVER (PARTITION BY UserId, Product)`. I am very new to Windowing Functions, but this would get me the earliest `Date` the user was seen in that `Product`, and then I can do another `SELECT` to check the `Date`? Will the window function make sure the `UserId, Product` are the same as the row it is calculating against?

Answer (score 0):

You query looks good so far. To check if this is the first time a customer uses a product, you can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to assign a rank to each record in groups of records having the same `UserId` and the same `Product`, ordered by `Date`. When the row number is `1`, you know that you are dealing with a new product.

```
SELECT 
    UA.UserId, 
    UA.Product, 
    UA.Client, 
    CASE 
        WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY UA.UserId, UA.Product ORDER BY UA.Date) = 1 
        THEN true 
        ELSE false 
    END AS IsNewProduct,
    CASE 
        WHEN UA.Date = FLS.Date
        THEN true
        ELSE false
    END AS IsNewClient
FROM UserActivity as UA
LEFT JOIN FirstLastSeen AS FLS 
    ON UA.UserId   = FLS.UserId 
    AND UA.Product = FLS.Product 
    AND UA.Client  = FLS.Client;
```

This **[demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/d93AtsLamAqV5QEpqynZx6/0)** with your sample data returns:

```
| UserId | Product | Client      | IsNewProduct | IsNewClient |
| ------ | ------- | ----------- | ------------ | ----------- |
| John   | Bank    | Mobile App  | 1            | 0           |
| John   | Bank    | Desktop App | 0            | 1           |
| Sally  | Gym     | Web App     | 1            | 1           |
```